# App crashing after splash screen in some phone

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming. My app is crashing after splash screen in few phones like OPPO F3 Plus but is working in Samsung Note 8, J7, MotoG. I am not able to figure out the reason. Here is a copy of my debugging console.

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 4 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f08008a (t=7 e=138) (error -75)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hu_tech.sat.loan, PID: 17400
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08008a
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1429)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:505)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.initialize(NavigationMenuItemView.java:114)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:442)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:361)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1255)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindo
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17400 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Logcat Errors are as given below:

> 10-28 22:38:37.625 1225-3722/? E/InputReader: POWER Key comes,
>   notifyKey - eventTime=19042493462000, deviceId=4, source=0x101,
>   policyFlags=0x0, action=0x0, flags=0x8, keyCode=0x1a, scanCode=0x74,
>   metaState=0x0, downTime=19042493462000
>       10-28 22:38:37.638 1225-3722/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Invalid hint ID.
>       10-28 22:38:37.665 1225-3735/? E/native: do suspend false
>       10-28 22:38:37.666 12964-12964/? E/wpa_supplicant: wpa_driver_nl80211_enable_filter: enable: 0, filter cnt: 12
>       10-28 22:38:37.669 614-3656/? E/bt_a2dp_hw: adev_set_parameters: ERROR: set param called even when stream out is null
>       10-28 22:38:37.768 1225-3722/? E/InputReader: POWER Key comes, notifyKey - eventTime=19042638180000, deviceId=4, source=0x101,
>   policyFlags=0x0, action=0x1, flags=0x8, keyCode=0x1a, scanCode=0x74,
>   metaState=0x0, downTime=19042493462000
>       10-28 22:38:37.780 1225-4727/? E/LocSvc_libulp: W/Loc HAL handshake did not happen yet...
>       10-28 22:38:37.782 1225-1241/? E/qti_sensors_hal: activate: handle is 53, en is 1
>       10-28 22:38:37.785 1225-1241/? E/qti_sensors_hal: thresh enable ,handle=53, en=1
>       10-28 22:38:37.819 21550-21550/? E/CrashHelper: Using hockeyapp id : ca4907e7617f425f31e0cf4f9a66e99e
>       10-28 22:38:37.835 614-21576/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
>       10-28 22:38:37.835 614-21576/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
>       10-28 22:38:37.931 1225-3702/? E/qti_sensors_hal: Thresh  processInd: prox data: data[0] = 5.000305, data[1] = 99.000000,
>   distance = 5.000305, timestamp = 948790718
>       10-28 22:38:37.932 1225-4534/? E/qti_sensors_hal: activate: handle is 53, en is 0
>       10-28 22:38:37.932 1225-4534/? E/qti_sensors_hal: thresh enable ,handle=53, en=0
>       10-28 22:38:38.277 21550-21550/? E/CrashHelper: Using hockeyapp id : ca4907e7617f425f31e0cf4f9a66e99e
>       10-28 22:38:38.278 21550-21550/? E/CrashHelper: Using hockeyapp id : ca4907e7617f425f31e0cf4f9a66e99e
>       10-28 22:38:38.278 21550-21550/? E/HockeyApp: NativeCrashManager is already enabled. Updating listener
>       10-28 22:38:38.279 21550-21550/? A/Adjust: PRODUCTION: Adjust is running in Production mode. Use this setting only for the build that
>   you want to publish. Set the environment to `sandbox` if you want to
>   test your app!
>       10-28 22:38:38.292 21550-21550/? E/CrashHelper: Using hockeyapp id : ca4907e7617f425f31e0cf4f9a66e99e
>       10-28 22:38:38.370 21550-21652/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
>       10-28 22:38:38.374 21550-21550/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:39.083 1225-3735/? E/WifiNetworkAvailable: wifi is not enable.
>       10-28 22:38:39.123 21531-21531/com.hu_tech.sat.loan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.hu_tech.sat.loan, PID: 21531
>           android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08008a
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1429)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
>               at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
>               at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:505)
>               at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.initialize(NavigationMenuItemView.java:114)
>               at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:442)
>               at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:361)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
>               at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1255)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16707)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5490)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindo
>       10-28 22:38:39.208 5157-7697/? E/ErrorSaveTask: /data/system/dropbox/data_app_crash@1540746519201.txt.gz log not
>   found!
>       10-28 22:38:39.208 5157-7697/? E/ErrorSaveTask: verifyError(): occur time is empty or app name is empty, return false
>       10-28 22:38:39.233 4618-4618/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:39.241 4618-4618/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:39.241 4618-4618/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:39.242 4618-4618/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:39.242 4618-4618/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:39.245 4618-5599/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:41.322 1225-1330/? E/BatteryStatsService: Wifi is in disabled state
>       10-28 22:38:41.383 5157-7697/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.nearme.feedbackservice.provider.data
>       10-28 22:38:41.383 5157-7697/? E/ErrorSaveTask: Cursor is null!
>       10-28 22:38:41.386 4618-4618/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:41.409 4618-4618/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:41.412 4618-4618/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:41.413 4618-4618/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:41.418 4618-4618/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>       10-28 22:38:48.079 1225-1359/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Failed to acquire lock.
>       10-28 22:38:48.130 1225-3735/? E/native: do suspend true
>       10-28 22:38:48.137 12964-12964/? E/wpa_supplicant: wpa_driver_nl80211_enable_filter: enable: 1, filter cnt: 12
>       10-28 22:38:48.159 614-614/? E/bt_a2dp_hw: adev_set_parameters: ERROR: set param called even when stream out is null
>       10-28 22:38:48.299 4335-21578/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error -4 during AudioRecord native read
>       10-28 22:38:48.300 4335-21578/? E/AudioProvider: audioRecord read failed
>           com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393221 | not open
>               at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.a.a(SourceFile:46)
>               at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.b.run(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.b.run(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.ci.bqX(SourceFile:2)
>               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.ch.run(SourceFile:2)
>               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.bk.run(SourceFile:3)
>               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.bk.run(SourceFile:3)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.m.run(SourceFile:6)
>       10-28 22:38:50.475 31037-21719/? E/HttpServerThread: I/O error initialising connection thread: Socket closed
>       10-28 22:38:50.475 31037-21719/? E/HttpServerThread: Thread is interrupted!!!

Comment: Are you using Vector icons?

Comment: You've forgotten to add the resource to one of the drawable folders. Make sure each resource you use is in each drawable folder.

Answer (score 3):

according to your logcat and your error , the activity could not find your resource file and this error is on onCreate method on setContentView method . 
so there is two possibilities :

1. You have a problem in your xml layer file and because of the problem android cannot parse xml correctly.
2. it in your app build files , and maybe files did not make correctly , to solve this clean your project first , make and build it.